# Update bar colors on chart based on axis labels that change each month

Tags: excel, vba

My chart measures factor returns placing the highest returning factor at the top of the chart. As the order may change on a monthly basis, I want to dynamically adjust the color based on the factor order.

I want to loop through each bar, match the factor name to the RGB code in my if statement block then move to the next bar.

What happens: The code starts on the first bar, correctly matches the bar to factor names color and moves on to the next cell instead of moving to next series.

```
Sub update_factor_barcharts()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Q26:Q31")

    For i = 1 To cht.SeriesCollection.Count
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If c = "Size" Then
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS19").Value, Range("AT19").Value, Range("AU19").Value)
            ElseIf c = "Value" Then
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS20").Value, Range("AT20").Value, Range("AU20").Value)
            ElseIf c = "Mom." Then
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS21").Value, Range("AT21").Value, Range("AU21").Value)
            ElseIf c = "Low Vol." Then
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS22").Value, Range("AT22").Value, Range("AU22").Value)
            ElseIf c = "Quality" Then
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS23").Value, Range("AT23").Value, Range("AU23").Value)
            ElseIf c = "Div. Yield" Then
                cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS24").Value, Range("AT24").Value, Range("AU24").Value)
            End If
        Next c
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Chart and factor names]

[image: RGB Codes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was trying to use nested for loops which was unnecessary. There is probably a more efficient way to do this but the solution below removing the outer for loop worked for me.

```
Sub update_factor_barcharts()
    '
    ' The order of factor returns can change each month
    'This macro automatically updates the charts to adjust for the changing order
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("Q26:Q31")

    i = 1
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = "Size" Then
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS19").Value, Range("AT19").Value, Range("AU19").Value)
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf c = "Value" Then
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS20").Value, Range("AT20").Value, Range("AU20").Value)
             i = i + 1
        ElseIf c = "Mom." Then
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS21").Value, Range("AT21").Value, Range("AU21").Value)
             i = i + 1
        ElseIf c = "Low Vol." Then
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS22").Value, Range("AT22").Value, Range("AU22").Value)
             i = i + 1
        ElseIf c = "Quality" Then
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS23").Value, Range("AT23").Value, Range("AU23").Value)
             i = i + 1
        ElseIf c = "Div. Yield" Then
            cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = RGB(Range("AS24").Value, Range("AT24").Value, Range("AU24").Value)
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is moving to the next cell because once the series is found and color changed, the if statement ends and the loop forces it to Next c.

Two options:

1. Make an if statement for each series within the 'c' loop so that once the series is found and altered, it checks the next if statement.
2. Instead of the 'c' For loop, use 'select case'. Easier than using a bunch of if statements.

Comment: Another suggestion: don't rely on VBA's defaults. Instead of `If c =` or `Select Case c`, use `If c.Value =` or `Select Case c.Value`.